# Macro with pattern matching in function's body

Tags: elixir

let's say we have 2 structs:

```
defmodule Algo.A do
  defstruct id: nil, foo: nil
end

defmodule Algo.B do
  defstruct id: nil, bar: nil
end
```

And following API which filters by struct type:

```
defmodule Algo do
  alias Algo.{A, B}

  def filter_by_type(collection, %A{}) do
    for %A{} = el <- collection, do: el
  end

  def filter_by_type(collection, %B{}) do
    for %B{} = el <- collection, do: el
  end
end
```

The intended behaviour is just to return a collection based on a match in comprehension:

```
    test "filters by struct type" do
      collection = [%A{id: 1}, %A{id: 2}, %B{id: 3}]
      assert [%A{id: 1}, %A{id: 2}] = Algo.filter_by_type(collection, %A{})
      assert [%B{id: 3}] = Algo.filter_by_type(collection, %B{})
    end
```

I would like to replace it by macro in something like:

```
for type <- [%A{}, %B{}] do
  type = Macro.escape(type)

  def filter_by_type(collection, unquote(type)) do
    for unquote(type) = el <- collection, do: el
  end
end
```

It doesn't work because the value under `unquote` in comprehension evaluates into `[__struct__: Algo.A, foo: nil, id: nil]` which matches on `foo = nil` and `id: nil`.
How exactly match *only* on struct's name, just to mimic what is in the top snippet?

Comment: Have you considered using a Protocol for this?  You can have multiple implementations of it, but the implementation that gets called depends on the 1st argument, so you'd need to do `filter_by_type(type, collection)`

Comment: Nah, I have 2 private functions which differ only in struct type used in pattern matching as above. Protocols would be too much I think. I want to make it a little bit DRY only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue lies in the difference between [Macro.escape/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Macro.html#escape/2) and [quote/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2).

`Macro.escape/2`, as a function, takes a term and returns an AST representing that term.

`quote/2`, as a macro, takes some code and returns an AST representing that code.

```rb
iex> Macro.escape %Algo.A{}
{:%{}, [], [__struct__: Algo.A, foo: nil, id: nil]}
iex> quote do %Algo.A{} end
{:%, [], [{:__aliases__, [alias: false], [:Algo, :A]}, {:%{}, [], []}]}
```

`%struct{}` as code is not exactly the same as `%struct{}` as a term, even though it often results in such. The code is a call to the [%struct{}](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%25/2) macro, rather than a true literal. When `%struct{]` is used in a match, only the provided keys are matched upon. Using the `Macro.escape/2` version expands all the key pairs before defining a match for the function.

So the simplest change would be to use `quote/2` in the list of types:

```rb
for type <- [quote do %A{} end, quote do %B{} end] do
  def filter_by_type(collection, unquote(type)) do
    # ...
```

That's more text per supported type, but you could shorten it by just including the module names. It wouldn't be exactly equivalent (you'd use literal atoms instead of alias AST), but from my experience it would work the same:

```rb
for type <- [A, B] do
  def filter_by_type(collection, %unquote(type){})
```

But you don't even need metaprogramming for this. You could just match on the struct dynamically:

```rb
# include "where struct in [A, B]" if you want to restrict structs
def filter_by_type(collection, %struct{}) do
  for %^struct{} = el <- collection, do: el
end
```

Or you could just pass the module instead of a struct if it matched your use case:

```rb
def filter_by_type(collection, struct) do
  for %^struct{} = el <- collection, do: el
end
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that I can pin structs like that! Thanks for the detailed answer!